# Bash custom autocompletion triggered by key

Tags: bash, autocomplete, customization, key-bindings, compgen

I really like Bash's programmable completion, but sometimes it does not include some files I'd like to autocomplete, so I have to type them manually.

I'd like to setup an alternate key (let's say `` ` ``) that when pressed triggers an alternate, simpler completion (for example just files and folders). As far as I can see, the completion I'd like is simply `compgen -f [text]`, so I'd like to wrap it is some function and possibly `bind` the key so that it triggers the completion with the last typed string.

I have been looking a lot but I can't seem to find how this would be done.

Comment: you mean like `\e/` which some distributions bind to `complete-filename` ? or `\C-x/` for `possible-filename-completions` ?

Comment: Yes, but hopefully with a behavior similar to `menu-complete` where one can get a list and cycle through options with the same key.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-complete_002dfilename-_0028M_002d_002f_0029), you should already have ...

- `complete-filename` bound to `C-x /` (first <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> together then <kbd>/</kbd>).
- `possible-filename-completions` bound to `M-/` (in most terminals, either <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> together, or first <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>/</kbd>)

What do they do? Assume your cursor is at the end of `cmd fil` and you have files `file1` and `file2` in your working directory. The former completes the command to `cmd file`. When pressed again, it shows the list of possible completions: `file1 file2`.
The latter shows the list directly, without completing anything.

#### How to bind to a single key?

See [bash's `bind` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-bind) and `man readline` in general.

In general, it is pretty easy: To bind the key <kbd>a</kbd> to filename-completion, use `bind a:complete-filename`. For the backtick <kbd>`</kbd> you would just do `` bind '`:complete-filename' ``.
However, if your operating system is configured with a keyboard layout that has deadkeys (*press <kbd>`</kbd> once, nothing seems to happen, press <kbd>e</kbd>, you get `è`*), then you have to press <kbd>`</kbd> twice, or your terminal and bash won't even see that you pressed that key. If you go for another key or special key or key sequence, similar things can happen. E.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> is usually processed by the terminal, before bash even sees it.

Comment: I managed to make your suggestion work, however I was wondering if there is a way to make the behavior the same as `menu-complete`? `complete-filename` always picks the first option and does not cycle, while `possible-filename-completions` is simply a list and does not perform any completion.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your goal in more detail. It seems like bash only supports *one* list of possible completions you can use with `menu-complete`. *Maybe*, you can `bind -x` the backtick  *and* `tab` to a bash function, that changes the possible completions every time you press the other complete button (*see the `complete` command, to define possible completions*). Not sure though, since that function also has to start `menu-complete` *after* it swapped out the possible completions. Maybe this can be done with one readline macro, that sends two more keyseqs.

Comment: That's more work than I planned to do here. I hope someone else can help you with that :)

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your time!